# How to check firewall rule before creating it using batch script and netsh

Tags: batch-file, netsh

I am attempting to create a batch file that user will just run and it will add a firewall rule, the script works but i want to prevent the user to creating multiple rules with the same name.

I know how to check it using netsh -contains but not sure how to convert it to a batch script.

my existing script

```
@Echo On
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "Open Port 80-90" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80-90

Exit
```

what i am trying to do

```
@Echo On
if netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Open Port 80-90" -contains "No rules match the specified criteria."
 
    @Echo On
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "Open Port 80-90" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80-90

Exit
```

Comment: Is the fact that there may be multiple rules with the same name of concern?

Comment: yes, its filling up on firewall inbound rules

Comment: So - the very fact that a rule of the same name exists means you won't add this new one, even though an existing rule with the same name might do something completely different?

Comment: @Magoo yes, if the rule name already exist i am trying the -contain then no need to add the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Open Port 80-90" | findstr /c:"No rules match the specified criteria." > NUL 2>&1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "Open Port 80-90" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80-90
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Rule already exists
    )
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory. `%ERRORLEVEL%` in this case is capturing the `errorlevel` of `findstr`, which will be `0` if the specified string is found.

Answer (score 3):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Open Port 80-90" > NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "Open Port 80-90" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80-90
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Rule already exists
)
```

is simpler.

The `netsh` command sets `errorlevel` to 0 if the rule exists, non-zero otherwise.